# Join multiples dataframes spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have multiples dataframes loaded from csv files i would like to join them based on a column , here what i did .i took just i would like to generelize and make it automatic.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
   import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
  val df1 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTestCsvFile/dataTest1.txt")
  val df2 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTestCsvFile/dataTest2.txt")
 val df3 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTestCsvFile/dataTest3.txt")
  df1.show
  df2.show
  df3.show
val df =List(df1,df2,df3).reduce((a, b) => a.join(b,Seq("time"),joinType="outer"))
   df.show
```

The problem it took just two of them not all them .The result is joining two of them
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for the answer

```
val df1 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTestCsvFile/dataTest1.txt")
      val df2 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTestCsvFile/dataTest2.txt")
     val df3 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv("C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/dataTestCsvFile/dataTest3.txt")
     val df_result=recursiveJoinOnDate(List(df1,df2,df3))
    df_result.show
      }
def recursiveJoinOnDate(list: List[DataFrame]): DataFrame = 
 { if (list.isEmpty){ null }else if(list.size >1){ list.head.join(recursiveJoinOnDate(list.tail),Seq("`time.1`"),joinType="outer") }else list.head }
  }
```